# Android Layout Highlight?

Tags: android

How to Highlight the Layout in Android?

Comment: Highlight when you touch them? Or to view wich part of the layout is being updated?

Answer (score 1):

I you're looking for help in determining how your layout is working, setting the background of an element can be very helpful as it shows how it is being sized.

Try something like:

```
android:background="#F00"
```

Answer (score 1):

The Android tool heirarchyviewer can help you view how your layout is being rendered.  It will draw boxes around each layout, and show you a tree of the layout components.  You can find it in your android sdk's tools folder.